# How to handle NULL values returned by a stored procedure from within SSIS package?

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

I am a newbie to ssis and am having issues with the loading the results of a stored procedure that includes NULL values into a table with ssis.   What I have is follows:

#### Step 1

Execute Stored Procedure on Database1 will return a Full Result Set and put into ADO object `User::CallResults`

#### Step 2

Then I Loop through the results of `User::CallResults` mapping 2 variables:

```
Variable         Index ADO object Type     Nullable  
User::ID         0      Object              NO  
User::Result     1        Object              Yes
```

#### Step 3

Then in the Insert Row Into Database2 takes each row and executes "insert into dbo.myTable id, result values (?,?)"

I map ID as int and Result as long respectively.

When I execute I get the error:

`failed with the following error: "An error occurred while extracting the
result into a variable of type (DBTYPE_I4)". Possible failure reasons:
Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly,
parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.`

Seems like this it errors when there is a null in the `Result`.  Any suggestions to make ssis allow nulls?

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing this in the Control flow instead of creating a ata flow?  What you're doing is exactly what the data flow is created for.

Comment: I will look into that, this was my first pass at solving the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the process that you have described in the question using `Data Flow task`. Here is a step by step description of fetching data using stored procedure and then inserting into a table, all done inside `Data Flow task`. This example is just to give an idea of how this can be done and it uses only a single instance of SQL Server.

**Step-by-step process:**

1. Create two tables named `dbo.Source` and `dbo.Destination` and populate the table dbo.Source with data as shown in screenshot #**1**. Create table scripts are provided under **Scripts** section.
2. Create a stored procedure named `dbo.GetData` using the script provided under **Scripts** section.
3. On the SSIS package, create a variable named `StoredProcedure` as shown in screenshot #**2**. This variable will contain the stored procedure execution statement.
4. Create an `OLE DB Connection` in the Connection manager to connect to the SQL Server instance.
5. On the `Control Flow` tab of the SSIS package, place a `Data Flow task` as shown in screenshot #**3**.
6. Double-click on the `Data flow task` to navigate to the `Data Flow` tab. Inside the Data Flow tab, place an `OLE DB Source` and an `OLE DB Destination` as shown in screenshot #**4**.
7. Configure the `OLE DB Source` as shown in screenshots #**5** and #**6**. Notice that the source is using the variable that was created in step #3. The data returned by the stored procedure will be the source input.
8. Configure the 'OLE DB Destination` as shown in screenshots #**7** and #**8**. This will insert the data into the destination table.
9. Screenshot #**9** displays sample package execution.
10. Screenshot #**10** shows the data in the tables after the package execution. Note that the destination table contains `NULL` values. This is possible because the column **Qty** can accept `NULL` values. However, if we had passed `NULL` values to the **ItemNumber** column, the package would have failed because the column is non-nullable.

Hope that helps.

**Scripts:**
.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Destination](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ItemNumber] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Qty] [int] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Destination] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Source](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ItemNumber] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Qty] [int] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Source] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetData]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT      Id
            ,   ItemNumber
            ,   Qty
    FROM        dbo.Source
END
GO
```

**Screenshot #1:**

[image: 1]

**Screenshot #2:**

[image: 2]

**Screenshot #3:**

[image: 3]

**Screenshot #4:**

[image: 4]

**Screenshot #5:**

[image: 5]

**Screenshot #6:**

[image: 6]

**Screenshot #7:**

[image: 7]

**Screenshot #8:**

[image: 8]

**Screenshot #9:**

[image: 9]

**Screenshot #10:**

[image: 10]

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but since code can't be formatted nicely in a comment I'm putting it here.

Do you realize, that if your databases are on the same server, you can do this:

```
INSERT INTO 
    database1.dbo.Results
EXEC 
    database2.dbo.SampleStoredProcedure @param1, @param2, @param3
```

Comment: Unfortunately they are on different servers and have to use different credentials to access.  Thanks I can see uses for this in other projects.

Answer (score 0):

Put this logic into a Data Flow.  After that is accomplished, just do a bulk insert and it should allow the nulls through.

[**SSIS - Unable to insert NULL for Blank fields in BULK INSERT**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/a23d6542-b0fa-4368-a1c3-0228e3187abc/)